# Ms Sql Insert Trigger To Affect Other Table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to put `table b` value when `table a` inserted but nothing effects on `table b`. Its like there is no `trigger`. Do you have any suggestion. I have tried below but no result.

```
alter trigger triggername on tablea after insert as
begin
update tablea set valuetablea_a = valuetablea_b where id = (select distince id from inserted)
end

begin 
update tableb set valuetableb_a = (select valuetablea_a from tablea where id = (select distincd id from Inserted))
where date = (select distinct date from Inserted)
end
```

Comment: You've abstracted your question too far and this is now clearly not even runnable code. Please try to describe with at least a *little* detail *what you're trying to achieve*. Maybe add some sample data for tables A and B and then describe what should happen when a new row is inserted into table A.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER triggername ON tablea AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

UPDATE a 
SET 
    valuetablea_a = I.valuetablea_b
    FROM tablea A
        INNER JOIN inserted I
            ON A.Id = I.Id

UPDATE B
    SET
        valuetableb_a = A.valuetablea_a 
        FROM tableb  B
            INNER JOIN tablea 
            ON 1=1 AND EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE ID = A.ID AND [Date] = B.DATE
            ) 
end
```

In the first update, you are giving this

```
update tablea set valuetablea_a = valuetablea_b
```

Which means From TableA update the value from column valuetablea_b to valuetablea_a for each row that was updated. Instead of getting the values from the Updated valuetablea_b column

2nd Update updates the values in TableB.valuetableb_a by matching the Id and Date fileds in the updated records

Comment: You can explain to the OP which will make your answer better ;)

Comment: Inner join on 1 = 1?